# What outlier score is used here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have come across a score function in a program, but I don't exactly understand what it does. This score is a measure of how probable a sampled/created value is. I will describe the procedure for computing the score function as accurately as I can.

Let $Y$ be a normally distributed random variable (I think this assumption is necessary, as evident in the following).

Furthermore, we are given a sample $\{y_n\}$ of $Y$ and compute the midrange of this sample, called $y_{\text{midr}}$. Then some statistic, in the code called $y_{\text{std}}$ is computed by

$ y_\text{std} = \frac{y_{\text{max}} - y_{\text{midr}}}{3}$
where $y_{\text{max}}$ is the largest value of the sample.

Finally, the score is computed for the value $y_{\text{true}}$:

$\text{score} = 2 \Phi(\frac{y_{\text{true}} - y_{\text{midr}}}{y_\text{std}}) - 1$

This just seems to be the scattering range of $y_{\text{true}}$ for the **cdf** of the standard normal distribution.

I then discovered some statement that checkes if the $\text{score}$ value is smaller than a certain threshold, but I have not found what this threshold is.

Is this a known outlier test, or some frequently used statistical test? Why is the midrange and this strange deviation used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $y_{std} = (y_{max} - y_{midr})/3$ is inspired by the fact that [99.7% of data will fall within 3 standard deviations of the mean](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-68-95-99-7-rule-for-a-normal-distribution-b7b7cbf760c2). This is sometimes called the [range rule](https://www.thoughtco.com/range-rule-for-standard-deviation-3126231) and is sometimes recommended as a way you can mentally calculate a rough standard deviation in your head.

The range rule is not a great way to estimate a standard deviation and in particular it is anti-robust and extremely sensitive to outliers. There are [robust ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale) to estimate the standard deviation such as [$s = IQR / 1.34896$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale#Estimation). (Here, "robust" means insensitive to rare outliers.)

The score part is simply the usual two-sided p-value for the [one sample z-test.](https://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=one-sample%20z-test)

I have never seen this used in a program (where there is always a library function which can calculate the usual [unbiased estimate of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance)). It makes little sense to use the range rule (which is really just a rule-of-thumb) if you have access to the full sample. The range rule estimate is particularly ill-suited to outlier testing, because it is guaranteed to overestimate variance if even one outlier is present in the sample.

Comment: Excellent answer! The program is a variational autoencoder: https://github.com/regel/loudml/blob/master/loudml/loudml/donut.py#L1145 and the function where the score is computed is called compute_bucket_scores. The sample is obtained by MC sampling (search for '# MC integration') to obtain reconstruction probabilities. It has its roots deep in Bayesian Stats, but I am no stat myself, so I can only guess why the author proceeded like this. If you have any idea if this could be related to MC sampling and reconstruction in the VAE, please let me know.